# Disable right-click menu in ComboBox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My ultimate goal is to make Combobox un-editable. Currently when user makes any selection then ComboBox shows selection and highlights it, therefore user can right-click and cut and delete the text that appears. I have added keyDown method, which prevents user from command such as ctrl + c, ctrl + v and delete. But User can still modify highlighted Text using right-click 'cut', 'copy' and 'paste'. How can i prevent user from modifying the current selection?

Comment: If the control is not actually a ComboBox, then why is your question about a ComboBox?

Comment: What's a `ComboGrid`? That's not a standard WinForms component AFAIK. Does it have documentation?

Comment: I would also like to know what is a `ComboGrid`, is it a 3rd party control?

Comment: Sorry for confustion. Control is actually ComboBox, but data inside is grid. So Control is just regular Windows.forms.ComboBox.

Comment: Regardless of how data is populated in ComboBox. Can you please help me figure out how can i disable right-click event from ComboBox. Thank you

Comment: If the control is a `ComboBox` then it has all the members that a `ComboBox` has, therefore you CAN set it's `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`. The question is WHERE you do that. Given that you have still chosen to keep the type of grid a secret, we can't really help you with that.  Consider providing ALL the relevant information in future.

Comment: Grid is simply DataGridView that is being populated through database. And reason i can't use .DropDownStyle property is because it doesnt let me add combobox.Text pragmatically.

Comment: What you are asking (if I understood it correctly, given the vague-at-best details you provided) is a way of disabling copying/pasting data from a combobox. Sorry, but there will always be a way of doing it in a way or another in _all major browsers_. If that's still your problem, consider implementing a windows forms application.

Comment: @EricWu this **is** winforms: "Control is just regular Windows.forms.ComboBox"

Comment: @Blorgbeard holy moses, you're right. I just found the comment in which he explains that. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ultimate goal is to make Combobox un-editable.

You could subscribe to `KeyDown` event and set `SuppressKeyPress` to true for all other actions other than `Ctrl+c` and create new `ContextMenu` to disable all default behavior.

```
 comboBox2.KeyDown += comboBox2_KeyDown;
 comboBox2.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();   //disable right click

 void comboBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (!(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C))
      {
           e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
      }
 }
```

Comment: What's that got to do with disabling right-click?

Comment: Ultimately OP want's disable all edits, so he could use `SuppressKeyPress ` to disable all edits.

Comment: `Keypress` <> mousebuttons...

Comment: And what about right-click -> paste?

Comment: That's valid point, let me update.

Comment: @Blorgbeard updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Zaggler now handled right click as well, please check.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question out of curiosity, why do we make new Context Menu. Because i assigned new ContextMenuStrip to comboBox's ContextMenuStrip and that works fine as well. If you can, please explain which one should i use?

Comment: Basically what we are doing here is assigning a dummy `ContextMenu` to disable the default ContextMenu behavior, both approaches are fine, you could use what ever you feel comfortable.